# I want to proof that the lebesgue measure of the set below is positiva. Help me!

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lebesgue-measure, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega$ be a domain limited with smooth boundary in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and consider the Sobolev space $H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$ equiped with the norm $||u||=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{2}dx$. Let $\{\phi_{k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$ be the eigenfunctions of the problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u=\lambda u, & \mbox{in $\Omega$}\\
u=0, & \mbox{on $\partial\Omega$}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
 Set $W=\langle\phi_{k}\rangle_{k=1}^{j}$ and $V=W^{\perp}$. Note that $H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)=W\oplus V$. I wnat to proof that for each $\epsilon >0$ there is a $v\in V$, with $||v||=\epsilon$, so that the set
$$A_{v}=\{x\in\Omega: w(x)+v(x)>1, w\in W, ||w||\leq 1\}$$
has positive lebesgue measure.

I tried to prove by contradiction, but could not.

I thank the help!